# Linq2Db streaming from database (ClickHouse)

Tags: c#, clickhouse, linq2db

Does the Linq2Db have a common approach for streaming results from the database?
This can be a raw response from the database or IEnumerable<MyObj> (which are internally obtained from the stream)

I would like to get the following behavior: a database query is executed and its result would be loaded not entirely into memory, but in chunks. At the same time, so that the receipt of each chunk does not look like a separate query to the database that is in no way connected with the previous one

Comment: Could you possibly provide a little more information about what you mean by streaming? Do you mean taking a large ranged query and chunking it up between multiple queries, opening a reader and running an action for each row (vs a bulk materialization), or to subscribe to an SQL notification-style listener?

Comment: There is a query to the database with where and orderby, the problem is that the result does not fit in memory. I would like to process it with chunks.
But a simple implementation implies code like `var chunk = queryable.Skip(chunkSize * currentChunk).Take(chunkSize).ToArray();` which leads to several queries to the database

Comment: > Do you mean taking a large ranged query and chunking it up between multiple queries, opening a reader and running an action for each row (vs a bulk materialization),   

Yes, only to request the form: 
`
select * from myTable
order by myTable.Date
`
   
When reading by chunks, did not force to sort again when reading the next chunk

Comment: It depends not so much on the ORM, as on the DBMS provider.

Comment: Try to use `ClickHouse.MySql` driver. Looks like it is one which supports streaming. So, just enumerate until the end.

Comment: Also streaming may work with `ClickHouse.Client`. But you should check it by yourself. We just briefly analyzed source code of supported providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For provider `ClickHouse.Client` a simple call to `AsAsyncEnumerable()` will work